# Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

A lot of people had the same error and most of their solutions worked, but not for me. I just can't see to run the code.

I tried `clean/rebuild`, `multiDexEnabled true`, I also tried tweaking the `.gradle` file which I just don't understand.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qrbarcodescanner"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
}
```

I just want to get rid of the pesky `Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED error`. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Add full error log.

Comment: > Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}